# What is the best way to write this RegEx expression for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing from input an script tag, and I want to transform it to something that can be latter written inside another script tag (follow me?), therefore I need to change `'</script>'` and also `'</SCRIPT>'` into `'</scr'+'ipt>'`

What is the best way to do this? I already have this, but it feels improbable that this is the best solution...

```
tag = tag.replace(new RegExp("</[sS][cC][rR][iI][pP][tT]>", "g"),"</scr'+'ipt>");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the case insensitive modifier:

```
tag = tag.replace(new RegExp("</script>", "gi"),"</scr'+'ipt>");
//                                    here _^
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you can use `/i` regex modifier that makes the whole pattern case-insensitive.

Besides, there are two ways to declare a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp): with a literal or constructor notation. Use the former when you have a known pattern, and use the latter when the pattern is built dynamically.

So, the best way to do what you need is using a **literal notation** with **/i** modifier:

```
tag = tag.replace(/<\/script>/gi, "</scr'+'ipt>");
                  ^          ^ ^
```

Note that in literal notation, forward slashes must be escaped, but you do not have to double escape shorthand classes and special regex characters (e.g. `\\s`, `\\w`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the case-insensitive flag i

```
tag = tag.replace(new RegExp("</script>", "g", "i"),"</scr'+'ipt>");
```

Comment: This is not how you do it. It’s supposed to be `("</script>", "gi")`, like the other answer.

Comment: You are correct. I was confused by the [, flags] notation in the declaration class declaration. I use too many languages simultaneously...